# How to Order By a Subquery result

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have 2 DB tables, `Events` and `Event_Dates` so each Event can have multiple Dates. I now try to read out the next upcoming event and a list of all upcoming events ordering by the date.

So I created the following query with a subquery, but the order by is ignored. After some research I realised that this is common, but I am still not sure how to work around this. Could somebody give me a hint?

My`Event` Table stores the Event Information like `Location`, `Event name` and `Description`. The `Event_Dates` table stores the `event_id` and one or multiple dates, if the event goes over more than 1 day. I

f I just check my Subquery then I get the correct order by the event_date, but the Main Query ignores that order by event_dates. So if I have the following in my event dates table

```
id | event_id | event_date
1  | 58 | 2019-02-23
2  | 59 | 2019-02-24
3  | 60 | 2019-02-09
```

The subquery returns `60`, `58`, `59` which is correct so I would like to display the events in that order, but instead it shows `58`, `59`, `60`.

```
Select * FROM events WHERE id in(
 select event_id from event_dates 
    where event_date >= NOW() order by ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),event_date))
)
```

UPDATE-

Great and quick help got me the solution and this is how it should look in Laravel:

```
         $events = Event::select('events.*')
                ->distinct('events.id')
                ->join('event_dates','event_dates.event_id','=','events.id')
                ->where('event_date', '>=', \DB::raw('curdate()'))  
                ->where('published',1)    
                ->orderBy('event_dates.event_date')   
                ->get();
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and the desired result.  You question does not make much sense.

Comment: I thought it did, sorry, I have added some more infos.

Comment: HINT: `ORDER  BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have recurring events. An event can have occured mutliple times in the past and can occur mutliple times in the future, too. You want to show future events ordered by their date. That's a mere inner join:

```
select e.*
from events e 
join event_dates ed on ed.event_id = e.id and ed.event_date >= now()
order by ed.event_date;
```

With events Christmas and Easter for the years 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, you'd get:

```
Easter
Christmas
Easter
Christmas
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a very simple solution, I don't know why I was not thinking in that direction. I have updated my question with the answer, since it had to be changed to fit into Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you just need a `JOIN` between two tables, properly filtered and sorted :

```
SELECT e.*, d.*
FROM events e
INNER JOIN event_dates d ON d.event_id = e.event_id AND d.event_date >= NOW()
ORDER BY d.event_date
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How simple that was.

Comment: You both had the same solution and both worked so I upvoted you both. Just not sure who should be the accepted answer, since you both deserve it.

Comment: Thanks GMB for taking that decision of my shoulders :-) while I have been starring on it for hours it took you both 2min to answer. Such fantastic help. Thanks a lot !